# Type after animation

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to type when my underscore is blinking with an animation? It looks like [this](http://lucafraser.nl/)

I want to be able to type when visiting the page. Nothing else, but I don't know if that is possible. Do I use animations or JavaScript for that? Can you someone help me with this?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  left: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.blinking-cursor {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #2E3D48;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Hi there </span><span class="blinking-cursor">_</span>
```

Comment: Of course it is possible. You can type at any time. Even when your computer is closed. Your question is currently incomplete. Please describe what you want to happen in your page when the visitor types.

Answer (score 0):

add `contenteditable="true"` to the div in your HTML and you're ready to go.